# My Blender model has invisible insides when exported to unity

Tags: unity

I have a crate that I got online and then customized and animated to open and close, and in blender the walls are visible on the inside, but in unity where I imported them they aren't, can someone please tell me why?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is invisible in Blender also.Have you switched on Backface Culling?[image]
If it works with this then you can add planes inside or you can solidify the external faces.

Answer (score 1):

OR, you didnt flip the normals in the inside of the box

Select the faces that are inside, click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and in the tool window tick the box that says **INSIDE**